# Looking for a way to correct CSS code preview

Tags: css, youtube

Can I add a string of css code in order to look for

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="...></iframe>
```

and transform it to

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"...></iframe>
```

or just remove the entire youtube block?

Comment: css can't alter the structure of a document (like changing an attribute or removing a node). You should use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the youtube iframe by using `display:none` and target the src attribute starting with the youtube url:

```css
iframe[src^="https://www.youtube.com"] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="></iframe>
```

But if you want to physically remove it, the you will need to use some javascript